# possibly lossy conversion strange error java

Tags: java

```
/    private static final 
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long arraySize=10_000_000L;
    // TODO code application logic here
    Long[] largeArray = new Long[10000000];// compiles OK
    Long[] myIntArray = new Long[arraySize];// compile error
}
```

Can some one help me understand why I am getting this compiler error.
"error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int"

Comment: You are using long as a size for an array, thats why and you cant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize an array with a long size.  You can only implement an array using an integer size *n* that satisfies:

```
0 <= n <= Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

See [Java SE specification > Array Access.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4)

> All arrays are 0-origin. An array with length n can be indexed by the
>   integers 0 to n-1.
>
> Arrays must be indexed by int values; short, byte, or char values may
>   also be used as index values because they are subjected to unary
>   numeric promotion (§5.6.1) and become int values.
>
> **An attempt to access an array component with a long index value
>   results in a compile-time error**.

Comment: While you're right, there's nothing at the link you provide that backs up or validates your claim.

Comment: Correct Makoto, I have revised my answer to include the Java SE spec. It specifically calls out compile-time exception for using long as length.

Answer (score 0):

"Arrays must be indexed by int values... An attempt to access an array component with a long index value results in a compile-time error." --- Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Java#Large_arrays